# Add "open in new window/tab" option to search results page

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface

Could you please add an option to the search results page to open links in a new window or new tab? This is available on Google, and is very useful.

Edit: I'm only after an option, not to force this on the user. As an amateur I'm often using SO to research a problem by reading up the answers to a number of questions, and want to open multiple tabs to compare what I find. In my eagerness to read a particular search result I might forget to Control + Click that link, then if it's not what I want I close down the tab... now I've lost my link back to the search page.

Comment: Most browsers you can right click on the link, a context menu will appear with that action. I believe since Netscape 2 youve had this option

Comment: I'll rather have the ability to launch a search from one tab into a new tab.

Answer (score 7):

To me, there is nothing more annoying than site forcing me to open links in new tabs or windows when I don't want them to. You can:

- Ctrl + left-click on a link to open it in a new tab.
- Right-click a link and choose to open it in a new tab or window.
- Middle-click on a link to open it in a new tab.

When some site decides to force links to open in a new tab or window, they should have a very good reason to do so. One useful place might be where you are editing or writing a question/answer, and click a help link. You might expect this helplink to open in a fancy pop-over so you won't loose your work. Forcing such a link to open in a new tab makes sure you won't loose minutes or hours of your work. The search result page is not such a place. When I click a link in the search results and I want to go back to the search results, I press backspace or click that arrow that is trying to puncture the left side of my screen. I'll get exactly the same search results back.

Tl;dr; I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: Well, technically he didn't request that links be *forced* to open in new tabs. He asked for an *option*, which Google does have in their search settings. However, Stack Exchange is not really a fan of implementing per-user settings such as this.

Comment: I was not aware of such an option O_o I thought I knew about everything in the world...

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer. I didn't know about the middle-click feature, thanks for that.