# Links inside questions and answers should have the option to open in new-tabs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, hyperlinks

**Links inside questions and answers should open in a new-tab or new window at-least.**

When reading through a question that contains links of images or other webpages or jsfiddles , it is very convenient to have all these small references open in a different tab or window, branch out if you will.

It is always good practice to have the main page open, so that we can "refer" to the links and then quickly close them if not required or switch away from them or to and from them.

Whether it will open in a new window or new tab is not the major concern, this can be changed by browser setting. However, the concern is that we are diverting from the main page.

Check out this [Site](http://www.w3schools.com/) W3 schools , when you click on the 'Try it Yourself ' button ,it opens in a new-tab, why? So that you can refer to the example and jump back to the study material.  Or even in our own SO if you click on an advertisement, a new-tab will open up. It would feel really annoying if it had opened in the very same page.

I am aware that I can open in new-tab by holding down the `ctrl-key`.
But,opening a sub-link in a new-tab....... is just plain good presentation skills (document presentation not website presentation) and we definitely need it here.

Or simply give us an option to select in user preferences the kind of link-behavior we would [prefer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2341/336166) . By the way, these are not just random links we are clicking on , we know the **context** of the link.   When one writes **"Here is a screenshot"** we know that is going to lead to an image. When one writes **"Here is the JSfiddle"** , we know its going to the JSfiddle page. Refer to this [answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/5400)  from Stackexcahnge UX.([Original reference](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/should-links-open-in-new-windows/#why-enforcing-opening-links-in-new-windows-is-wrong)) He writes

> "In the second situation users would simply click on the link and **suddenly** find out that the link is opened in a new window."

We are all programmers here. We know what the link is going to open, so there is no question of anything suddenly happening.

If you read this article [Open New Windows for PDF and other Non-Web Documents](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/open-new-windows-for-pdfs/) by Jakob Nielsen. He concludes by writing

> "I thus stand by the old advice against opening new windows while users are **browsing the Web**."

Again, I mention, we are not just browsing the web here, we know what links we are clicking on.

Similarly,  in this article , [Beware of Opening Links in a New Window](https://www.sitepoint.com/beware-opening-links-new-window/) he concludes with

> "Think very long and very hard before you open links in a new window. Most of the time, opening links in the current window is by far the best solution. If you do need to open links in a new window, at least warn users beforehand — unless, of course, you want your site visitors to get a rather unwelcome surprise!"

Frankly speaking, a new user could find anything as an unwelcome surprise or sudden. A simple one line in the formatting documentation could let them know that **all links within the answers/questions will open on new-tabs.** Thus,the surprise will be eliminated.

As we know [Every rule has an exception](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/should-links-open-in-new-windows/#every-rule-has-an-exception) .

Having said all that now, if the SO site wants to go by the construct of

> **Letting the user decide where the link opens**

Then **do** let the user decide, because while reading a SO question or answer I am definitely expecting the link to open on another window or tab.
Here we see an [Optimal solution](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/should-links-open-in-new-windows/#optimal-solution)  where a mere checkbox and javascript gets the job done.

Comment: This is most certainly *not* "good presentation skills", it is [very bad web etiquette](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/the-top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-1999/). What other major sites open all of their links in new tabs? (Hint: W3Schools is not a model of a good site.)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276173/automatically-open-jsfiddle-in-a-new-tab, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309971/on-click-open-image-link-to-the-next-tab, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260386/add-open-in-new-window-tab-option-to-search-results-page, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199436/jsfiddle-and-other-live-code-services-in-new-tab, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168063/allow-per-user-settings-to-open-external-links-in-the-same-or-a-new-tab, ...

Comment: @CodyGray.....I know its `very bad website etiquette` , but in this scenario **practicality** dictates that we need this feature.

Comment: Unless that practicality is "the Ctrl key broke on my keyboard", I'm not seeing it. Stack Overflow users are programmers, and expected to be competent users of the web. If they want to open a link in a new tab, they know how to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray....Nice one :p !!! Tell me, why do the advertisements on the Stackoverflow pages open in new windows or tabs ? Where is the etiquette gone there?

Comment: I don't know what advertisements you're talking about. There are either no advertisements visible for me, or I never click on them. Like the Careers ads? Yeah, I see those, but I've never clicked on one. If they break the rules, I have no idea why. Advertising is often known for breaking the rules, it's why so many users block it.

Comment: Based on the answers to the cross-site dupe you linked to, apparently there used to be a user script for this. Maybe [ask if this already exists](http://stackapps.com/tags/app-request/info)?

Comment: To be fair there are some links which are treated differently on the stack exchange network. For example on the Board Gaming site you can use a tag for magic the gathering cards that will create a popup window when clicked on to get information about a card. But that was a special case that was coded for.

Comment: Your "optimal solution" is far from optimal. It's not up to each individual site to reimplement this setting, so that every site plays by its own rules. That leads to a horrible inconsistent experience for everybody. Just **learn to use your browser**. You get to choose each time you open a link exactly how you want that link opened. This is an extremely solved problem.

Comment: @meagar....It is still an extremely unsolved problem. It doesn't need to be a horrible inconsistent experience for anyone : Let the site keep its defaults , the visitors are happy. **Just provide an option for those who prefer it.** The only horrible experience is may be for the developers. And if you think about it, it could actually be **better for the server.** Imagine ONE answer with 4 links , 2 images , 1 js fiddle and one external link. To go back and forth it will take 8 requests. But if you just open those 4 links in 4 tabs, thats it, 4 requests. And u can go back and forth as manytyms

Comment: @DannyBoi nice question I suppose to write the same question but I come here I find a long debate :p. the main reason of the open link in a new tab is I forget where I am back forward ruining my bandwidth to and killing time also for page load and rendering. I surprise to see -20 on that question .

Comment: This is analogous to retail websites sending of email "offers" to customers. Some customers love it, others hate it. All should be given the option to enable or disable this feature. Ditto for whether links are displayed in the existing browser tab or a new browser tab. Let users have their choice.

Answer (score 21):

There are multiple options a user can chose from, to open a link in a new tab.

I don't want to be forced to a new tab when I want to open the link in the same window.

Neither can you rely on browsers respecting the site's suggestion of where a link should open, as browsers can easily ignore said configuration.

Basically: Let the *user* decide where the link opens. Don't try to force it.

Comment: `Basically: Let the user decide where the link opens. Don't try to force it.`
Fair enough, then why is the advertisement being opened in a new-window/new-tab?

Comment: @DannyBoi: "*why is the advertisement being opened in a new-window/new-tab?*" Because advertisements are not about the content of the question/answer. They are about something else. Therefore if you click one, you are far more likely to be mentally task-switching. Whereas if you click a link in a post, you're simply looking up more information on the subject.

Comment: "Let the user decide where the link opens" -- if you want to open the link in a new tab in the foreground, that isn't an option. ctrl + click is *not* the same as a link that opens in a new tab by default.